# How to handle drawing multiple of the same shape in OpenGL ES

Tags: android, opengl-es, shapes

I've been programming for about a couple years now, and I know the syntax of different languages pretty well, but I've spent most of my time making programs in basic Lua. I have played around with game developing with Java and C#, with DirectX and OpenGl, but most times I don't even know terms that others may know really well such as 'shaders' and 'VBOs'. I've heard of them, but I really don't know what they mean, so **please explain to me like I'm five** if you have a answer.

I'm trying to make a simple Android game using Open GL ES 2.0, and, I've seen many tutorials explaining how to draw one triangle, and not many. For my case, I have a world full of triangles, its simply an array of true and false's, where if there is a true a triangle will be drawn in that position, if false the triangle won't be drawn. I've made it so it will only draw triangle's until they are off screen, but I realized one problem still, and that is that rendering is still super slow, takes about 2 seconds to render one frame.

At the moment, I currently 1 triangle class, and when it checks if a triangle is supposed to belong where it is, it will create vertex points for that triangle and pass them into the triangle class, then creating a new triangle object with those updated vertices. Now I can see how wrong this can go, but it's honestly the only thing I can come up with, with my very-limited knowledge on OpenGL ES

What I am looking for is to draw all of these triangles, in their correct position, with the same color and size, in a very efficient way, so that it wouldn't take about 2 seconds to draw one frame.

If anyone has a solution, Thank you.

Comment: I would recommend doing a Google search for GLES tutorials (e.g. http://www.learnopengles.com/android-lesson-one-getting-started/). One example that may be of use is Android Breakout, which manages to achieve 60fps despite using unoptimized code (no VBOs in sight) -- https://github.com/fadden/android-breakout . Two full seconds to render is pretty extreme.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is for instanced draw calls that basically means that you are going to send one VBO (Vertex Buffer Object - this holds all the information about the vertex of a mesh) and an array of MVPM(Model View Projection Matrices - These hold all the transformations information of every draw you want to do of that VBO) to the shader, all this in one single draw call.

unfortunately for us (i'm using right now OpenGL Es 2.0 as well) there is no way provided by opengl to do this.

Any way, there is this article about fake [that](http://carloscarrasco.com/faking-mesh-instancing-in-opengl-es-20.html) but i think is too much trouble.

In other words ir are pretty much trapped with a draw call per mesh.